# I'm looking for a dataset which provides information about gas leak in a pipeline

Tags: data-request

I am currently doing a project on gas leak source localisation in pipelines for which large number of data is required but i have not got a good dataset from other sources.So i would like to know if a dataset is available or any gas leak simulation platform is available for me to work.the data must have the location of the leak and the concentration of the gas that was leaked and a minimum of 1000 values is required for training it.Most sets only show location and do not specify leak concentration.I have not been able to get my hands on industrial data regarding these pipeline leaks.

Comment: I had put to answers in the original question before it was answered: are either of interest?  https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15475/1511

Comment: What should be in that dataset, in what form, how much data, etc.? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: thank you for the suggestions,I was unaware due to me being relatively new to this field.I have already checked through your answer philshem which i am thankful for but they do not specify concentration of leak